# Pattern matching on a discriminated union

Tags: f#

Is there any way to pattern match on discriminated union functions, e.g.:-

```
type Test =
  | A of string
  | B of int
  | C of char

let DefaultTest t =
  match t with
  | A(_) -> A(null)
  | B(_) -> B(0)
  | C(_) -> C('\u0000')

let a = A |> DefaultTest
```

Obviously this code isn't valid F# as DefaultTest accepts one parameter of type Test rather than 'a -> Test. Is there any way of achieving this *without* specifying a value for the discriminated union?

What I'm after, ultimately, is a function which inputs a function of type 'a -> Test and outputs Test(default value of 'a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not clear what you are after, but does this help?

```
type Foo =
    | A of int
    | B of string

let CallWithDefault f =
    let x = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    f x

let defaultA = CallWithDefault A    
let defaultB = CallWithDefault B    
printfn "(%A) (%A)" defaultA defaultB
```

Comment: Brilliant. That is exactly what I need!

I feel very stupid now...!

Comment: Would you like "A Unchecked.defaultof<_>" more?

Comment: *faints* Wonderful. Yes, that fun -> ... smelt of being a bit redundant.

Comment: I think the ultimate is Unchecked.defaultof<_> |> A, reads like English prose, plus works in parameter lists without parentheses. I see you're a dev on the F# team - big thank you for F# from me, the language is blowing me away. Very. Beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're after but something like:

```
let DefaultTest (t :obj) =
  match t with
  | :? (string->Test) as a -> Some (a null)
  | :? (int -> Test) as b -> Some (b 0)
  | :? (char -> Test) as c -> Some (c '\u0000')
  | _ -> Option.None
```

might work for you...

Comment: Really excellent answer, however Brian's answer happens to resolve my precise problem more generically!

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly work when all the constructors had the same argument type, say int.
Then one could

> match t 0 of
>     | A 0 -> ...
>     | B 0 ->
>     ...

Comment: Unfortunately the argument types have to be able to be different...!